# Creating a DOM element for every AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple application that retrieves restaurant/place of interest information from the yelp api and creating a "card" (via materialize) for every response. Here is my code below.

```
 function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {    
            createMarker(results[i]);

            result.push(results[i].name);
            address.push(results[i].vicinity);
            queryUrl2 = queryUrl + "location=" + address[i] + "&term="+result[i] + "&limit=1";
            var cards = $('<div class="card blue-grey darken-1"></div>');

            function cardMake(){ 

            $(".cards").append(cards);
            }

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: queryUrl2,
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer xyz",
            }}).then(function (response) {


                        console.log(response.businesses[0].name);
                        cards.text(response.businesses[0].name);

        }) 

          cardMake();
        }

    }

}
```

What is happening is that the cardMake() which creates cards is only making a single card for one restaurant and not multiple cards for the rest of the places retrieves from yelp. Any help on how to create a card for each restaurant is appreciated!

Comment: I believe `response.businesses` is an array of *places* - or whatever - which you want to create cards for, right? Why won't you loop through it?

Comment: There is some code is missing but I can say that there is a problem of async call here. So rather to create multiple card it is creating single card.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous. You need to move some code inside the promise continuation.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: queryUrl2,
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer xyz",
  }}).then(function (response) {
    var cards = $('<div class="card blue-grey darken-1"></div>');
    cards.text(response.businesses[0].name);
    $(".cards").append(cards);
  });
```

and yes, you also have to consider looping through `response.businesses` instead of just grabbing the first element `response.businesses[0]`